# .htaccess : if php file does not exist return 404, otherwise redirect to index.php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am tying to write a .htaccess file that returns a 404 if a .php ( other than the index.php ) file is requested.

Also when a .html ( other than an index.html ) is requested to redirect to the index.php.

I have no code to show because none of it worked.

Thank you

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but generally if you dont want files directly available, put them outside the web root

Answer (score 0):

Apache rewrite rules can achieve what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On

# index.php allowed - no more rules to apply
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# if static .html file does not exist, redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if your web application is served under web root:
RewriteRule \.html$ /index.php [L]
# if your web application has a prefix, substitute @VHOST_WP_PREFIX@:
# RewriteRule \.html$ @VHOST_WP_PREFIX@/index.php [L]

# 404 for other .php files
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, now how would I just allow html files with page at the begging of the url : page-1-2-3-4-5.html and 1-2-3-4-5.html will not be allowed.  Thank you

Comment: in response to @user3188033: The '\.html$' is a regular expression, so using expression '^page.*\html$' instead, will match 'page-1-2-3-4-5.html', but not '1-2-3-4-5.html'. See the [Apache rewrite module documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for further details.